# Unable to add or delete documents even after getting the reference for a particular document

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a weird error while trying to work around with Firebase. This is the first time I'm using it(hence it's a basic CRUD query). While trying to add documents, I'm passing values via a form to add documents. And while deleting, I'm getting the ID as reference to delete the document. But neither of them are working. Would appreciate some help with this.

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app'
import {
getFirestore, collection, getDocs,
addDoc, deleteDoc, doc
} from 'firebase/firestore'
```

After importing the requisite functions, I try to add the documents into the database.

```
//adding a document through form values

const addRecipe= document.querySelector('.add');
addRecipe.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
    e.preventDefault()

    addDoc(colRef, {
        title : addRecipe.recipe.value,
        author : addRecipe.author.value,
    })
    .then(()=>{
        addRecipe.reset();
    })
})
```

Similarly, I try to delete a document after getting the reference,

```
    //deleting a document by fetching the ID

const deleteRecipe= document.querySelector('.delete')
deleteRecipe.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
    e.preventDefault()

    const docRef= doc(db,'recipes', deleteRecipe.id.value)

    deleteDoc(docRef)
    .then(()=>{
        deleteRecipe.reset();
    })
})
```

[NB:I am able the fetch the documents from Firebase that I manually created, but unable to add/delete through the code I provided above.]

Providing my HTML code snippet as well for reference,

```
<body>
    <div class="container my-5">
        <h1>Recipes</h1>
      

        <form class="add">
            <label for="recipe">Add a new recipe</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe" required>
                
            </div>
            <label for="recipe">Add author</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" required>
            </div>
            <button>Add a recipe</button>
            
        </form>


        <form class="delete">
            <label for="recipe">Recipe ID</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" required>
                
            </div>
            <button>Delete a recipe</button>
            
        </form>



    </div>
   
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Not exactly sure what the error is here since I am passing values and referencing properly as is required.

Putting up my Firebase collection details as well which I added manually.
[image]

Comment: We can't see the values that you're passing to Firestore, nor can we see the contents of your database, so we have no way of seeing what might be going wrong here.  I'll also point out that you're not checking for errors on the call to add a document. Something could be going wrong and you'd never know.  Please read about how to provide [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to improve your question.

Comment: I have tried catching the error, it doesn't show any. As for the values, I'm passing it through the form. As I mentioned, only the values that I have added manually to Firestore is being retrieved, the ones via the form submit are not.

Comment: Did you verify your Rules are set to allow read and write when authenticated?

Comment: Yes, I did. The rules do allow allow read and write.

Comment: If anyone could help, it would be a huge help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the security rules to enable read and write at all times(not recommended; since this is not in production and just a basic project to familiarize with Firebase, I used this method. For me, setting up the timestamp to a later date didn't work as well for some weird reason, hence the reason I went with this. I have contacted the Firebase support team to clarify.)

You could try setting up Firebase Authentication and updating your security rules for authenticated users only. This is safer and a better solution. This link would help.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth